# Dart, Compareto two situations in same time on list items

Tags: flutter, dart

I have formatted dateFormat items, I mean : 11-08, 22-12 "dd-MM" items in a list. I want to sort them from the nearest date to farthest date. I did use compareTo like that (tumKisiler is a list)

'''

```
tumKisiler.sort((a, b) {
                    return a.siralamaDogumTarihi
                      .substring(3, 5)
                      .compareTo(b.siralamaDogumTarihi.substring(3, 5));
```

'''
but that is only sort by months. I want to sort by days also.
The  output must be look like that :
13-08
26-08
17-09
31-12

How can I do that? I am new here, I hope could explain.

Comment: If it was me I would add a int to the item, when formatting the date originally, of `"formattedDate".millisecondsSinceEpoch / 1000`. Then you can just sort using that variable with a `>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to sort on the month and day without adding the year. When I format DateTimes, I cannot use the MillisecondsSinceEpoch method because it is strings now.